# Mounting OSX directory to AWS EC2 instance launched with Docker Machine

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

I'm trying to figure out an approach to mount a directory on my OSX machine to an AWS EC2 instance I've launched with Docker Machine. After some searching online, it sounds like one approach is to use sshfs in concert with docker-machine, although I'm not entirely clear how to make that happen. I've found a reference to this here but I've not been able to get it to work. https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/691

Any thoughts on how I can make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve? Mounting a local drive on an AWS instance isn't something people normally do.

Comment: I'm using a GPU-backed EC2 instance for machine learning experimentation. In the spirit of the workflow mentioned here, I wanted to try using sshfs to mount a local directory on the remote instance to simplify my dev workflow. http://killianlevacher.github.io/blog/posts/post-2016-07-22/post.html